# Looking for a simple one-dimensional noetherian domain whose regular locus is not open

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

In the [wikipedia webpage for "excellent ring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring), one finds the following.

> If R is the subring of the polynomial ring k[x1,x2,...] in infinitely many generators generated by the squares and cubes of all generators, and S is obtained from R by adjoining inverses to all elements not in any of the ideals generated by some xn, then S is a 1-dimensional Noetherian domain that is not a J-1 ring as S has a cusp singularity at every closed point, so the set of singular points is not closed, though it is a G-ring. This ring is also universally catenary, as its localization at every prime ideal is a quotient of a regular ring.

I am not sure what the "elements not in any of the ideals generated by some xn" are, because no xn lies in R. Also I am not able to prove noetherianity. In fact, I am not sure that the example has all the claimed properties.

In Exposé XIX of the volume "Travaux de Gabber" in Astérisque 363-364, there is an example of a one-dimensional noetherian domain whose regular locus is not open, with ordinary double points as singularities at closed points.

I understand this latter example, but it is much more complicated than the former and I'd really like to find an example simple enough to be presented in a colloquium-style talk.

Can anyone help me understand the wikipedia example, or find an example in the same vein?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This example appears as Example 1 in the following reference:

> Melvin Hochster, *Non-openness of loci in Noetherian rings,* Duke Math. J. **40** (1973), 215–219. [MR311653](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=311653). [ZBL0257.13015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0257.13015). DOI: [10.1215/S0012-7094-73-04020-9](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-73-04020-9).

In fact, the example in question is a special case of the general result quoted below.

> […] $K$ denotes a field and all otherwise unspecified tensor products
>   are taken over $K$. If $R$ is a $K$-algebra, we say that $R$ is
>   *absolutely* Noetherian over $K$ if for every overfield $L \supset K$, $L \otimes R$ is Noetherian. If $R$ is a localization of a finitely
>   generated $K$-algebra, then $R$ is absolutely Noetherian over $K$. $R$
>   is *absolutely* a domain over $K$ if, likewise, each $L \otimes R$ is
>   a domain, and $P$ is absolutely prime if, equivalently, either $R/P$
>   is absolutely a domain or each $L \otimes P$ is prime (in $L \otimes R$).
>
> […]
>
> **Proposition 1.** *Let $\{R_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of absolutely Noetherian $K$-algebras indexed by an
>   infinite set $I$, and for each $i \in I$, let $P_i$ be a nonzero
>   absolutely prime ideal of $R_i$. Assume that each $R_i$ is absolutely
>   a domain.*
>
> *Let $R' = \bigotimes_{i \in I} R_i$. Then $R'$ is a domain and for
>   each $i$, $P_iR'$ is prime. Moreover, if $S = R' - (\bigcup_i P_iR')$
>   and $R = S^{-1}R'$, then $R$ is a Noetherian domain whose maximal
>   ideals are in one-to-one correspondence with $I$ via the map $i \mapsto P_iR$. In addition, each nonzero element of $R$ belongs to
>   only finitely many maximal ideals, and for any maximal ideal $P_iR$ of
>   $R$* $$R_{P_iR} \cong (L_i \otimes R_i)_{P_i^e},$$ *where $L_i$ is a
>   certain extension field of $K$ and $P_i^e$ is $P_i(L_i \otimes R_i)$.*
>
> *In particular, if for each $i \in I$, $R_i$ is a subring of a
>   polynomial ring over $K$ and is generated by a finite nonempty set of
>   forms of positive degree and $P_i$ is the ideal generated by these
>   forms, then the hypotheses of the first paragraph are satisfied, and
>   the conclusions of the second paragraph hold. Moreover, the local
>   rings of $R$ are algebro-geometric in this case.*

In Example 1, Hochster applies the Proposition to the situation where $I$ is the set of positive integers and $K$ is an arbitrary field, in which case he sets $R_i = K[x_i^2,x_i^3]$ and $P_i = (x_i^2,x_i^3)R_i$ for each $i$. Then, $R_{P_iR} \cong L_i[x_i^2,x_i^3]_{P_i^e}$ for every $i$, which is a non-normal local domain of dimension one. By the Proposition these are the localizations of $R$ at nonzero prime ideals, and the only regular point in $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is the generic point corresponding to the zero ideal.

It is useful to note the following consequence of Proposition 1, also in Hochster's paper:

> **Proposition 2.** *Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a property of local rings and suppose there is an algebro-geometric local ring $(R_1,P_1)$ over a
>   field $K$ such that*
>
> 1. *$R_1$ is absolutely a domain,*
> 2. *$P_1$ is absolutely prime, and*
> 3. *for every overfield $L \supset K$* $$(L \otimes R_1)_{P_1^e}$$ *fails to have property $\mathscr{P}$.*
>
> *Suppose that each field $L \supset K$ has $\mathscr{P}$. Then there is a locally algebro-geometric Noetherian domain $R$ over $K$ in which the $\mathscr{P}$ locus is not open.*

This gives a nice way to construct rings that are locally excellent but not excellent, for instance.

Comment: Thank you! This perfectly answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

The standard method they must be referring to is this: suppose given a field $k$ and geometrically integral finite type $k$-algebras $R_n$ and maximal ideals $\mathfrak m_n \subset R_n$. Then one constructs $R$ as the localization of
$$
S = \text{colim} (R_1 \otimes_k R_2 \otimes_k R_3 \otimes_k \ldots \otimes_k R_n)
$$
at the multiplicative set of elements $f$ which are not contained in
$$
\mathfrak q_i = \text{colim}_{n > i} (R_1 \otimes_k \ldots \otimes_k \mathfrak m_i \otimes_k \ldots \otimes_k R_n)
$$
for any $i$. Note that $\mathfrak q_i$ is a prime ideal and that the singularity of $S$ at $\mathfrak q_i$ is (more or less) the same as the singularity of $R_i$ at $\mathfrak p_i$. Namely, $S_{\mathfrak q_i}$ is a localization of $L_i \otimes_k R_{\mathfrak m_i}$ for some geometrically integral field extension $L_i/k$. Every prime of $R$ corresponds to a prime of $S$ contained in $\mathfrak q_i$ for some $i$. Then it follows that $R$ is Noetherian because all prime ideals are finitely generated (for example).

This was explained to me by János Kollár on a hike in Utah some day (as something that commutative algebraists do). I hope others will provide references to the literature or give better answers.

Comment: Thank you! So the wikipedia page actually means to say, "adjoining inverses to all elements not in any of the ideals $m_n=(x_n^2,x_n^3)$" right ?